# Environment setup failed (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, enthought, canopy

I tried to setup Canopy on a cluster, but always failed.

I followed the instruction and typed the following line:

```
~/Canopy/canopy_cli setup ~/canopy
```

The error messages are:

```
Setting up installation in /home/xxx/canopy... 

 No handlers could be found for logger "canopy.app.util" 

Traceback (most recent call last): 

   File "/home/xxx/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86_64/__boot__.py", line 9, in <module> 
     sys.exit(main()) 

   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/app/bootstrap.py", line 2220, in main 

   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/app/bootstrap.py", line 2186, in send_bug_report 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run_factory_reset'
```

How can I solve this problem?

The above problem can be solved by changing another folder.

But I met another similar problem.

```
No handlers could be found for logger "canopy.app.bootstrap"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/wangyuw/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86_64/__boot__.py", line 9, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/app/bootstrap.py", line 2220, in main
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/canopy/app/bootstrap.py", line 2186, in send_bug_report
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run_factory_reset'
```

I still do not know how to deal with it.

Comment: The ~/canopy folder is where your macros and a few other things are stored. You should ideally not be installing a virtual environment in ~/canopy. Try installing into a different location than ~/canopy. Does that work fine?

Comment: Thanks! It works! But another cluster showed a different error message. I still do not know how to deal with it.

Comment: Please edit your question here (at the bottom of your original question, not replacing it) to provide your new information. I have marked your new post which follows up on this, as "Ignore or Delete".